# Como fazer o padding de um item <li> oculpar 100% verticalmente do container?

Tags: html, css

Consegui calculando o tamanho exato da barra e colocando o valor no padding, mas isso me causa problemas depois, como faço para ele ficar como na imagem abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
 <html lang="pt-br">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <title>Document</title>
        <style>
             * {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            :root {
                --texto-branco: #f2f2f2;
                --fundo-preto:#222;
                --fundo-azul:#009DFF;
            }

            nav {
                background: var(--fundo-preto);
                height: 64px;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .logo {
                color: var(--texto-branco);
                margin: 16px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            ul {
                list-style: none;
            }

            li {
                padding: 0px 16px;
                display: inline-block;
                transition: .3s;
            }

            nav li:hover {
                background: var(--fundo-azul);
            }

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: var(--texto-branco);
            }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <nav>
                        <div class="logo">VM</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fale Comigo</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque `display: flex` em tudo: `nav`, `ul`, `li` e `a` (é bom criar classes para esses elementos, senão irá afetar o site todo). Use a propriedade `align-self: stretch;` na `ul`. Essa propriedade fará com que o elemento ocupe toda a altura da `nav`. E com `align-items: center` você centraliza verticalmente os elementos:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    --texto-branco: #f2f2f2;
    --fundo-preto:#222;
    --fundo-azul:#009DFF;
}

nav {
    background: var(--fundo-preto);
    height: 64px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}

.logo {
    color: var(--texto-branco);
    margin: 0 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-self: stretch;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    transition: .3s;
}

nav li:hover {
    background: var(--fundo-azul);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--texto-branco);
    padding: 0px 16px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <div class="logo">VM</div>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Fale Comigo</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Agora, o `padding: 0px 16px` deve ser colocado no `a` e não na `li`, caso contrário o link `a` não irá ocupar toda a área da `li` onde está.

E a logo você pode usar apenas `margin: 0 16px;`, pois ela será centralizada automaticamente no flexbox.

Comment: Para um site simples qual seria o mais adequado, calcular o tamanho do padding ou fazer desta maneira?

Comment: Calcular padding é gambiarra. O certo é usar desta maneira pq fica tudo automático.